# How to get symbol and amount of a transaction in solana network?

Tags: transactions, account

I'm new to solana network and technology. I'm developing an application to confirm transaction receive to a specific wallet address on solana network. Right now I'm using this API "api.mainnet-beta.solana.com" .My question is how to get amount and symbol of a transaction ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you've already identified the transactions that are interesting to you, you will find `preTokenBalance` and `postTokenBalance` fields in the [transaction](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#results-42) metadata, both with [this structure](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#token-balances-structure).

- To get the transfer amount, first coerce the `uiTokenAmount` field(s) into a number however is most convenient for the language you're using.  Then take the difference of the two.
- The `mint` field can then be used to query something like the [Solflare Unified Token List API](https://github.com/solflare-wallet/utl-api#get-by-mints) for the extended token metadata, which contains they symbol.

Comment: Just wanted to add this regarding token symbol and name :
with the token metadata being moved onchain, one can directly fetch the metadata account of a token and deserialize it, the new metaplex sdk does it farily trivially, this way if you dont trust an api and want to directly get it via the contract you can do so.

Comment: For metaplex, this might be useful https://chainstack.com/the-mystery-of-solana-metaplex-nft-metadata-encoding/